# Convert Yolo output to a real-world coordinate system

Tags: yolov5, wgs84

We have detected objects on UAV data using Yolo v5 and obtained bounding box coordinates `(x1,y1,x2,y2)` in the format relative to the origin of the satellite data. The data looks like this and is returned as a tab-delimited text file.

```
[ 7953 11025  7978 11052]

[16777 10928 16817 10970]

[15670 10591 15685 10607]
```

The results are accompanied by a PNG and the PGW (world file) reads like this:

```
0.1617903116883119
0
0
-0.1617903116883119
655854.20159515587147325
2716038.70000312989577651
```

How can the bounding boxes be converted into real-world global projection EPSG:4328 usable in GIS? Any hints towards a python script are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[go in Detect.py and set gn = 1 and it'll get you the un-normalized coordinates. Attaching the screenshot below for you reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8jOG.png)

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to convert 'post detection' to avoid re-detection?

Comment: I am sorry couldn't understand the question, can you please explain further?

Comment: I have already detected the objects, which took a few days. I want to avoid rerunning the analysis and just convert the output.

Comment: That is pretty simple, if you've detected by setting the save_text parameter to True then the results are already being stored in runs/detect/labels/{Filename}.txt, you can refer to that file and convert the results accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this short function to convert the yolo detections to real-world polygons. The yolo `detections.txt` needs to be read without the `[]`.

```py
# function to return polygon
def bbox(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # world file content
    # Line 1: A: x-component of the pixel width (x-scale)
    xscale = 0.1617903116883119
    # Line 2: D: y-component of the pixel width (y-skew)
    yskew = 0
    # Line 3: B: x-component of the pixel height (x-skew)
    xskew = 0
    # Line 4: E: y-component of the pixel height (y-scale), typically negative
    yscale = -0.1617903116883119
    # Line 5: C: x-coordinate of the center of the original image's upper left pixel transformed to the map
    xpos = 655854.20159515587147325
    # Line 6: F: y-coordinate of the center of the original image's upper left pixel transformed to the map
    ypos = 2716038.70000312989577651

    X_proj = xpos + (xscale * x1) + (xskew * y1)
    Y_proj = ypos + (yscale * y1) + (yskew * x1)

    X1_proj = xpos + (xscale * x2) + (xskew * y2)
    Y1_proj = ypos + (yscale * y2) + (yskew * x2)

    return Polygon([[X_proj, Y_proj],
                    [X1_proj, Y_proj],
                    [X1_proj, Y1_proj],
                    [X_proj, Y1_proj]])

outGDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = dataset.apply(lambda g: bbox(int(g[0]),int(g[1]),int(g[2]),int(g[3])),axis=1),crs = {'init':'epsg:32638'})
```